# Return Results from CoreData directly into Class

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm new to Swift and iOS development. This is probably a simple misconception on my part.

I'm using core data. I have four attributes in my entity:
"title" type String
"longitude", "latitude" type Decimal
"timestamp" type Date

In the code below I'm getting the error "'[Locations]' is not convertible to '()'".

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Locations)
class Locations: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var title:String
    @NSManaged var longitude:Double
    @NSManaged var latitude:Double
    @NSManaged var timestamp:NSDate

    class func getAllLocations(){
        let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Locations")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

        return results as [Locations]

    }
}
```

Comment: Most tutorials about CoreData I've found have been lazy about data models suggesting looping through the results and using 'if let 'title'= result.valueForKey... I'd love some insight into how others interface with CoreData please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler complains because you did not specify a *return type* for your function,
it should be

```
class func getAllLocations() -> [Locations] { ... }
```

There are also some unnecessary type annotations, and all the *objects* can be
declared as constants:

```
class func getAllLocations() -> [Locations] {
    let appDel =  (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Locations")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    return results as [Locations]
}
```

Note also that

```
let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
```

will throw a runtime exception if the executing the fetch request failed.
You should use an optional binding and some error handling or fallback,
for example

```
if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as? [Locations] {
    return results
} else {
    // Failed, return empty list. (Alternatively, report error.)
    return []
}
```

Comment: @jackreichert: You are welcome. – Btw, `@NSManaged var longitude:Double` should be `@NSManaged var longitude: NSDecimalNumber` for a "Decimal" attribute. Did you let Xcode create the managed object subclass?

Comment: Ah thank you. I did not, I created it myself. I'm trying to find better CoreData management then what the basic tutorials are suggesting. And saw something similar in a code sample in github.